# Download webrtc source code error

Tags: webrtc

I have been downloading webrtc source code for a month and haven't done it yet. Everytime I got the same error:

```
Error: Command download_from_google_storage --directory --recursive --num_threads=10 --no_auth --bucket chromium-webrtc-resources trunk/resources returned non-zero exit status 1 in /Users/xxx/work/webrtc/depot_tools
Hook 'download_from_google_storage --directory --recursive --num_threads=10 --no_auth --bucket chromium-webrtc-resources trunk/resources' took 20.05 secs
```

The depot_tools is just downloaded and it's absolutely new. Can someone tell me how to solve it? This is the step I followed:

```bash
$  svn co  http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/tools/depot_tools
$ cd /Users/xxxx/work/webrtc/depot_tools
$ gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
$ gclient sync --force
$gclient runhooks --force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it by finding this piece of code in trunk/DEPS and remove it
  {
    # Download test resources, i.e. video and audio files from Google Storage.
    "pattern": "\.sha1",
    "action": ["download_from_google_storage",
               "--directory",
               "--recursive",
               "--num_threads=10",
               "--no_auth",
               "--bucket", "chromium-webrtc-resources",
               Var("root_dir") + "/resources"],
  },

this method is found in this link https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=2811